# Conditions for $f'(n) \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

If it is known that $$\log(N) > \int_{2}^N \frac{f'(x)}{x^{\alpha}}dx$$ and $f'$ is continuous can we conclude that $f'(x) \to 0$ as $x\to \infty$ ? Or some monotony conditions must be imposed on $f'$ to have that conclusion (that $f' \to 0$)? Here is what I've tried: I arrived at the conclusion given any constant $\epsilon > 0$ follows that $f'$ cannot have all it's values above $\epsilon$, hence $\it{if}$ $f'$ is decreasing then $f' \to 0$ indeed. But can that monotony hypothesis be removed? Or more generally what conditions (sufficient) must $f'$ meet to have the conclusion $f'(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can construct functions $f$ for which $f'$ is continuous, that integral is finite and the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ does not exist. Take $g$ to be a nonnegative continuous function which is piecewise affine. It is zero most of the time except in the intervals $(-\frac1{n^2}+n,\frac1{n^2}+n)$ where you take it to be in such a way that $g(n)=1$. Then take $h(x)=x^\alpha g(x)$ and $f(x)=\int_0^x h(t)\,dt$. Then $f'(x)=x^\alpha g(x)$ and so
$$\int_0^N\frac{f'(x)}{x^\alpha}dx=\int_0^Ng(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{4n^2}.$$
If you want the inequality  $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{4n^2}\le\log N $ you might need to start the triangles at some larger integer instead of $n=1$. It is definitely true for all $N$ sufficiently large since the series converges. 
Then $\limsup_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=\limsup_{x\to\infty}x^\alpha g(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^\alpha g(n)=\infty$ since $g(n)=1$ (I am assuming that $\alpha>0$, you did not specify).
So you do need to assume that $f'$ is decreasing if you want the limit to exist.